# putting array list into a tree

Tags: java, tree

I need to insert the million hash codes into a tree. For each of the million hash codes, capture the time it takes to determine if the Linked List contains the hash code.  Use System.nanoTime() to get the time in nano seconds. Determine the mean and standard deviation of the timing performance of the Linked List for searching.
Likewise, determine the mean and standard deviation of the timing performance of the Tree for searching.

I have the code for inputting the million hash codes into a linked list and finding the mean and SD, but i am stuck on putting this into a tree. Could someone point me in the right direction??

```
 import java.util.*;


 public class DataStructureTiming
 {

public static void main(String[] args)
{  
  int MAXIMUM = 5;//initializing the maximum integer
  int MINIMUM = 1;//initializing the minimum integer

  Random randomGenerator = new Random();//initializing the generation of random integers

  int range = MAXIMUM - MINIMUM + 1;//setting the range of integers from 1 to 1,000,000

   ArrayList<Integer> randomNumbersHashCodes = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);//initializing an ArrayList to store the generated random integers with the capacity of 1,000,000

   ArrayList<Integer> randomNumbersStorage = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);

   //ArrayList<String> randomNumbersStrg = new ArrayList<String>();//initializing an ArrayList to store store the generated hashcodes into a string

  for (int index = 1; index <= 5; ++index)//for loop to generate 1,000,000 random integers in a range from 1 to 1,000,000
  {
        int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(range) + MINIMUM;

        randomNumbersStorage.add(randomInt);

        randomNumbersHashCodes.add(String.valueOf(randomInt).hashCode());//storing randomly generated numbers in a ArrayList

  }//end of for loop for random number generation and storage in an ArrayList

  System.out.println("Random generated number:" + randomNumbersStorage);
  System.out.println("Hash codes for random numbers:" + randomNumbersHashCodes);

   ArrayList<String> randomNumbersStrg = new ArrayList<String>(randomNumbersStorage.size());
   for (Integer myInt : randomNumbersStorage)
   {
     randomNumbersStrg.add(String.valueOf(myInt));
   }

   List<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<String>();//initializing Linked List
   linkedList.addAll(randomNumbersStrg);//adding generated hashcodes to Linked List

  System.out.println(linkedList);

  List<Long> durations = new ArrayList<>(randomNumbersHashCodes.size());
  for (int n : randomNumbersHashCodes)
  {
      long start = System.nanoTime();
      randomNumbersHashCodes.contains(n); // true
      long end = System.nanoTime();
      durations.add(end - start);
  }


  ***this is where i am having problems********
  Tree< Integer > tree = new Tree< Integer >();

  for (int x = 0; x <= 4; x++)
  {
     tree.insertNode(randomNumbers);
  }



  System.out.println(durations);

  //to calculate mean and SD of Durations
  long sum = 0;
  double sd = 0;
  for (int toCalcSum = 0; toCalcSum < durations.size(); toCalcSum++)
  {
     sum += durations.get(toCalcSum);
  }

  for (int toCalcSD = 0; toCalcSD < durations.size(); toCalcSD++)
  {
     sd += ((durations.get(toCalcSD) - sum) * 
           (durations.get(toCalcSD) - sum)) / (durations.size() - 1);
  }

  System.out.println("Sum of time: " + sum);
  System.out.println("Mean: " + (sum/durations.size()));
  System.out.println("SD: " + sd);



}//end of main method
}
```

Comment: Are you supposed to write the `Tree` class or use `TreeSet` or something else ?

Comment: I got the tree to work but i have no clue whats required by: Then, using the Java Container Class for LinkedList  determine the mean and standard deviation of the timing performance. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Looks like you have already written the code to collect the timing data and calculate the mean and the standard deviation.  So apply that code first to the `LinkedList` data and then to the `Tree` data.

Comment: capture the time it takes to determine if the Linked List contains the hash code. Determine the mean and standard deviation of linked list and tree. 
Then, using the Java Container Class for LinkedList determine the mean and standard deviation of the timing performance
Then, using the Java Container Class for a HashSet determine the mean and standard deviation of the timing performance
Compare the timing and statistics of the four different data structures.    Misha, these are my class instructions. Could you help me figure out what 4 things I need to find the mean and sd of?